# Limit Get-ChildItem to Show a Specific List of Files

Tags: powershell

I have a list of files that I want to view with Get-ChildItem. How do I limit [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) to only that list of files? Here is what I have tried:

```
$files = "1419624548.jpg","1419624652.jpg","1419624723.jpg"

# zero results
Get-ChildItem -include $files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does it:

```
> $files = "1419624548.jpg","1419624652.jpg","1419624723.jpg"
> Get-ChildItem -Path $files

    Directory: C:\Users\BigFont\Desktop\image-temp


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         14-Jan-15   4:06 PM    3456010 1419624548.jpg
-a---         14-Jan-15   4:06 PM    3762648 1419624652.jpg
```

Comment: Note that you could also pipe the array: `$files | Get-ChildItem`